# adding additional text to to the right of a <ul> list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a list that I will use a product spec sheet. This is the code I have so far:

```
<div class="productspec">

<ul>
<li>Product Description</li>
<li>Device Type</li>
<li>Bundled Services</li>
<li>Form Factor</li>    
<li>Processor</li>
<li>RAM</li>
<li>Hard Drive</li>
<li>Data Link Protocol</li>    
<li>Power</li>
<li>Dimensions (WxDxH)</li>
<li>Manufacturer Warranty</li>
<li>Bundled with</li>    
</ul>

</div>
```

Each feature will appear on the left of the list but I now want to have the description for each feature on the right of each one.

This is how I want it to look but I cant figure out the best way to do it

[image]

Is it possible to do this by putting the feature descriptions in the same list?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7DS4L/)

Comment: Use definition lists https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl or a table

Comment: I think a table would be a better way to achieve this.

Comment: agree with above a table would be a much better solution, or you could use the css display: table options and create it with div etc

Comment: @SimonDavies Why use `display: table` and not `<table>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use nested multiple `span` tags inside the `li` element, and assign `display: inline-block;` to the `span` tag and assign some fixed `width`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7DS4L/1/)

```
.productspec {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#CCC;
}

.productspec li:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: rgb(245,245,245);
}

.productspec li {
    text-indent:10px;
    line-height:30px;
    list-style:none;
}

ul li span {
    display: inline-block;
}

ul li span:nth-of-type(1) {
    width: 250px;
}
```

---

Also, I would like to say that using `table` for tabular data is not wrong, this seems to be like a tabular data, using `table`, `tr` and `td` will make your job much much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

### On style sheet add padding as per your requirement

```
  <style type="text/css">

    span{ padding-left:20px;}

    </style>

    <ul>
    <li><span> Product Description</span>   <span>Product Description2</span></li>
    </ul>
```